# C++ How to store element in deque without copying

Tags: c++, pointers, deque

I want to store pointers in a deque that looks like this:

`deque<ofImage *> pointerDeque;`

```
void testApp::iTakeAPointer(ofImage * &pointer) {
     cout << "iTakeAPointer  " << &pointer << endl;
     pointerDeque.push_back(pointer);
     cout << "pointerDeque.back() " << pointerDeque.back() << endl;
}
```

When I run it I get (function is called on keypress):

```
keyPressed 0xbffff240
iTakeAPointer  0xbffff240
pointerDeque.back() 0x9f2e08
```

Because deque.push_back() creates a copy. My question is: how do I get the reference, in this case 0xbffff240, in the deque?

EDIT:

Thanks. Sometimes you don't see the wood for the trees.

Answer (score 4):

Your diagnostics are incorrect. This is printing the address of the pointer, not the address the pointer holds (which is what you want):

```
cout << "iTakeAPointer  " << &pointer << endl;
```

`&pointer` is of type `ofImage**`. Just use `pointer`:

```
cout << "iTakeAPointer  " << pointer << endl;
```

---

Note, it must be the case that the `ofImage` instances contained in `pointerDeque` exist for its lifetime. If `pointerDeque` now owns the `ofImage` instances then consider using `std::unique_ptr`. If it does not own it, consider using `std::shared_ptr` (or `boost::shared_ptr`).

Comment: Thanks. It is the case that ofImage instances exist for its lifetime. I will look into std::shared_ptr anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
cout << "iTakeAPointer  " << pointer << endl;
```

Print the pointer itself, and not its address!

Answer (score 0):

```
void testApp::iTakeAPointer(ofImage * &pointer) {
```

change to

```
void testApp::iTakeAPointer(ofImage * pointer) { // remove ref
```